# Finding solution for a linear system(see below)

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

Consider the following linear system:

$     -2y + 3x=3$

$   3x + 6y + 3z=-2$

$6x + 6y+3z=4$

So I've tried solving this using Jordan-Gauss emilimination, scaling it down to row echelon form then to reduced row echelon form but am doing something wrong.

All help is greatly appriciated!

Comment: Show us your work, and maybe we can tell you where you have gone astray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second and the third equations give $x=2$

and from the first we obtain $y=1.5$ and the rest for you.